# Understanding Contractions and Fixed Points.

Tags: real-analysis

Definition: Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space. A function $f: X \rightarrow X$ is called a contraction if there exists $0\leq \alpha<1$ such that for every $x,y \in X$, we have $d(f(x),f(y))\leq \alpha \cdot d(x,y)$.

Then, the fixed point theorem follows. I have an example and I cannot find the fixed point:

$X=\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{2} \cdot (x-1)$. Then, for every $x,y \in X$

$$\lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert = \lvert \frac{1}{2} \cdot (x-1) - \frac{1}{2} \cdot (y-1) \rvert = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \lvert x-y \rvert \leq \lvert x-y \rvert $$ 
Thus, $f$ is a contraction. But, what is the fixed point? I simply shift everthing to the left and shrink a little bit. Am I missing something? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Solve $f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course $x = -1$ is a fixed point, since $f(x)  =x$.

Another way of thinking is this : the graph of the function you have is a straight line with slope $\frac 12$. The line $y =x$  is a straight line with slope $1$. Since the slopes are different, these lines must intersect at some point : this point is a fixed point.

So for linear functions with non-one slope (i.e. $f(x) = ax+b$ with $a \neq 1$ ) , you will have a fixed point just by the geometric notion of meeting lines, even if $f$ is not a contraction. For example, $f(x) = 2x+1$ is not a contraction, but has a fixed point since $x = -1$ is again fixed.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking very generally. Now, I see my stupid mistake :)

Comment: No problem, silly  mistakes will be cut with time.